# SML: Error: match redundant and Warning:match nonexhaustive

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am getting both of these issues for this function:

```
fun funion([(x:int list,y:bool list)]) =
let
 fun join(nil,final) = final |
     join(x::xs,final) = join(xs,union(x,final)) |
     join(_,final) = final
in
 join([(x,y)],(nil,nil))
end;
```

Here is the error:

```
sets.sml:30.6-32.27 Error: match redundant

(nil,final) => ...

(x :: xs,final) => ...

-->   (_,final) => ...

sets.sml:28.5-35.4 Warning: match nonexhaustive

(x,y) :: nil => ...
```

Does anyone know what might be going on here? I also tried join(_) but that did not work either. Not sure what the problem is here.

uncaught exception Error

Edit:

Here is the definition of union:

```
fun union((w:int list,x:bool list),(y:int list,z:bool list)) =
let
 fun join((nil,nil),final) = final |
     join((w::ws,x::xs),(intfinal,boolfinal)) = if x andalso elementOf(w,(intfinal,boolfinal))=false then join((ws,xs),(w::intfinal,true::boolfinal)) else join((ws,xs),(intfinal,boolfinal)) |
     join(_,final) = final
in
 join((w,x),join((y,z),(nil:int list,nil:bool list)))
end;
```

Comment: What is `union`? It is neither defined by you nor part of the standard basis. Also -- is it really your intention to define a function (`funion`) which can only apply to a list with 1 element? I don't see any reason for `funion([(x:int list,y:bool list)]) ` as opposed to `funion (x:int list,y:bool list)`.

Comment: I declared union myself. It finds the union of 2 sets of integers. funion finds the union of n-number of sets. So I recursively call join on the current set and the union of all the previous sets up to that point.

Comment: You should include `union` if it is part of your definition, and explain a little more clearly what the intended input and output of `funion` are.

Comment: I added the definition of union to the OP. The input of funion is a list of (int list * bool list) and it is supposed to return (int list * bool list) which is the union of all the sets in the list.

Comment: And what is `elementOf`? Ideally, questions should be self-contained.

Comment: elementOf: int * (int list * bool list) -> bool checks if an integer is a part of a set. So elementOf(2, ([2,3],[false,true])) returns false because 2 is not part of the set {3}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that `funion` is supposed to have type

```
(int list * bool list) list -> (int list * bool list)
```

But -- you only provide a definition for lists of length 1, which gives a non-exhaustive list warning.

For the inner function `join` you provide a definition first for patterns of the form `(nil, final)` and then for patterns of the form `(x::xs,final)`. Since the first component is either empty or matches the pattern `x::xs` and any list whatsoever matches `final`, any further pattern is redundant. Perhaps you want the three patterns

1) `(nil,ys)`

2) `(xs,nil)`

3) `(xs,ys)`

A final remark -- if you are happy with `union` -- why not just use it with `foldl` or `foldl` if you have a list of `(int list * bool list)` and what the union of them all?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As to why I am not using foldl, it is because this is an assignment for my class.

Answer (score 2):

"Error: match redundant" means that a pattern doesn't match anything that previously-tested matches wouldn't also match. In your case, you have the match-pattern `(nil, final)` (which matches any pair whose first element is the empty list) and the match-pattern `(x::xs, final)` (which matches any pair whose first element is a non-empty list), which together cover all cases . . . and then you have the match-pattern `(_, final)`, which doesn't match anything new. Technically this doesn't need to be an error — the compiler could just issue a warning and discard this match — but it's such a serious warning that SML/NJ treats it as an error.

"Warning: match nonexhaustive" means that your match-patterns don't cover all cases. In your case, the match-pattern `([(x:int list,y:bool list)])` can only match a single-element list. (You probably just meant to write `(x:int list, y:bool list)`, without the `[...]` notation to match a list of hardcoded length.)